# Meaning of AWS Lambda statistics - Average, Sum, Maximum, Minimum & Sample count, IQM, etc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, metrics

I was trying to make sense of the invocations metrics for an AWS Lambda function.
However, I am not sure how to make sense of it.

1. When the metrics are set to to Maximum, Minimum, Average, the graph shows only 1.
2. When the metrics are set to Average, Sum or Sample count there's a graph that shows values.

I went through their docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Statistics-definitions.html but the explanations did not match the observations.

Here are screenshots for reference:

### [image: Average]

### [image: Minimum]

### [image: Maximum]

### [image: Sum]

### [image: Sample count]

[image: IQM]